# php getElementsByTagName with specific attribute

Tags: php, xml, dom

I think this gets the first element called `<gallery>`

```
$gallery = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName('gallery')->item(0);
```

I'm trying to get `<gallery name="Third">`

I think I need something equivalent to:

```
$gallery = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName('gallery[@name="Third"]')->item;
```

Thanks, Andy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only possible with [DOMXPath](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), e.g.

```
$xp    = new DOMXPath($yourDOMDocument);
$nodes = $xp->query('//gallery[@name="Third"]');
```

or by iterating over the node list after the call to `getElementsByTagName` with

```
foreach ($objDOM->getElementsByTagName('gallery') as $gallery) {
    if($gallery->getAttribute('name') === 'Third') {
         // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Using *//gallery* is different to *getElementsByTagName()* called on the Document, because it just matches the "gallery"-Elements on the root level, instead of every "gallery"-Element.

Comment: @Sebastian not true. `//gallery` matches any gallery element anywhere in the document (or below a context node). This *is* equivalent to using `getElementsByTagName()`

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests *getElementsByTagName()* only accepts tag names. Try XPath instead

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath ($objDOM);
$nodeList = $xpath->query('gallery[@name="Third"]');
$gallery = $nodeList->item(0);
```

Dont tested it, so there may be errors, typos or something.

Comment: Of course, don't know why I didn't do it like that in the first place! Cheers.